# Listen port 843 and server crossdomain.xml from httpd.conf

Tags: apache

is it possible to configure the httpd.conf which listens the port 843 and serves crossdomain policy tags or file when there is a socket connection? (not for http request, needed it for socket connection from flash)

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this apache module, which will load the necessary socket policy files alongside any other standard crossdomain.xml configurations you need to host on port 80 - http://www.beamartyr.net/articles/adobepolicyfileserver.html

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not.

httpd.conf configures Apache which is a webserver, so expects to receive HTTP requests over the socket.  Adobe in their infinite wisdom decided that the Flash security policy file should be served over a home-brew protocol where the first string from the client is "\0".

Since Apache won't recognise that, it can't serve the requested file.

I could have a long rant here about the bogus-ness of this - it would have been (IMO) just as easy for Flash to have sent a "GET /policyfile" request which would have allowed Apache to serve the file, but there we go.

Your only option is to run a different server specifically to serve the policy file - Adobe provide some sample code in Python and other languages that does the job.